# Корзина с размерами товаров

Tags: php

Как правильно сделать корзину с выводом размеров товаров? ООП. MVC. Товары хранятся в другой таблице и связаны по id.

Comment: читайте Gang of Four, Code Complete. Там найдете ответы на свои вопросы

Answer (score 0):

В корзине кроме ид товара надо будет хранить еще ид размера товара. Просто дополнительное поле.

И давать возможность выбирать размер товара в карточке товара и в корзине, забирая список размеров из таблицы размеров.

Никакого ООП и MVC - может быть Active Record